# Add text before the first comment in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

In a WordPress single post, if there are multiple comments, how can I insert some text before the **first** comment?

I tried to use `#add_filter( 'comment_text', 'add_text_to_comments' );`. But it seems to apply every single comment.

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on whether the theme you are using is providing a hook for that. If it isn't then you'd probably have to edit the `single.php` file and just add your text above the code that adds the comments (eg. `comments_template`).

Comment: @DRogueRonin Thanks! I get it working. However, is there any WordPress hook function to do that?

Comment: That's entirely up to the theme author. If they haven't added one then there isn't.

Comment: @DRogueRonin Get. Thanks very much!